# What is the weak limit of $f_n \ \mathrm{sign}(f_n - 1)$ if $f_n \to f$ weakly in $L^p([0,1])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f_n: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a uniformly bounded sequence in $L^p$.  If $f_n \to f$ weakly in $L^p([0,1])$ (up to subsequences), what is the weak limit of the sequence of functions $$g_n = f_n \ \mathrm{sign}(f_n - 1),$$ where sign is the [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)? Can we write it in terms of $f$? Note that $g_n$ is also uniformly bounded in $L^p$, hence it has a weak limit $g$ (up to subsequences). What is the relationship between $g$ and $f$?

Answer (score 0):

The question was edited after In posted this answer.

$(g_n)$ need not converge weakly. [Uniform boundedness only tells you that there exists  a subsequence which converges weakly].

For a counter-example take $f_n=1+\frac  1 n$ for $n$ even and  $f_n=1-\frac  1 n$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously I meant up to subsequences and edited my question accordingly. What can be said about the relationship between the limit of $g_n$ and the one of $f_n$ (which are both up to subsequences)?

Comment: In my example there are two subsequential limits for $(g_n)$. $f_n \to 1$ weakly but there are subseqeunces of $(g_n)$ convergingto $1$ And $-1$. So how can all subsequential limits be related to the limit of $(f_n)$? I think your question has no definite answer. @Lao